# Struts Plugin for Eclipse Helios (Ubuntu)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, struts

> Are there any **Struts Plugins** for
>   **Eclipse Helios** - that make it easier to **Navigate through Struts based
>   Projects**? I am on an Ubuntu system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Eclipse and from menu select Help->Install New Software.

Add the following update site using 'Add' button

```
http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/
```

Select Struts present under 'Web and Java EE Development'

Comment: Can this be used even if I use Tomcat as the server??

Comment: Yes it can be. I hope you are using the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers. http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr1

Answer (score 1):

the above link do not run, eclipse Helios 3.6 has your own links to Jboss, select something like this, and then < struts tool > acept all...(I install Jboss Tools and Strut Tool) 
Select from the combo box 
Work with 
http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/helios
and open Web and Java EE Development, click in Strut Tools