# Struts 2.x Plugin for Eclipse 3

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, struts2, eclipse-plugin

I've searched and only found JBOSS tools for struts which are still pointing to 1.2 version of Struts. Are there any plugins for eclipse that work with Struts 2.x version?

Comment: The JBoss Tools I was referring to are suggested in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016174/struts-plugin-for-eclipse-helios-ubuntu

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic on Stack Overflow. You can ask on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ but be sure to [provide enough information](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Comment: Your question is OT in SO. Take a look at [StrutsClipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/strutsclipse).

Comment: @AleksandrM cool! I've starred it on github :) BTW with Convention it doesn't work, right ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios: Currently it is only for struts.xml file. Contributions are welcome. ;)

Comment: Can you share me the link to GIT?

Comment: @KrishnaVedula: There is a link in marketplace.